# Get minimum value in an array and then get index

Tags: arrays, powershell, minimum

I want to get the minimum value in an array of unique elements, and then get the index of that item, in one step without writing my own loop or looping through the array twice. If I have to loop, please let me know.

I know I can just do the

```
$b = ($a | Measure -Minimum).Minimum
```

But then I have to do

```
[array]::IndexOf($a, $b)
```

And while that is normally okay, I'm looking for a way to do it once because I'm running this many times in a loop.

Comment: What would you want happen in an instance where there are multiple entries in your array that have the minimum value? For example, in this array `1, 2, 3, 1, 4`, there would be more than one index returned if you got the index of the minimum value.

Comment: @Toomaja All of the values in the array are unique, apologies for not stating that in the main post.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I might consider a different data structure.  Maybe something sorted to begin with...

This code may work for your needs:

```
$myArray = 5,66,4,33,2,9,9,12


$index = 0
$minIndex = 0
$minValue = [int]::MaxValue
$myArray | % { if ($minValue -gt $_) {$minValue = $_; $minIndex = $index}; $index++ }

"MinIndex $minIndex = MinValue $minValue"
```

Comment: FYI, pipeline iteration with a scriptblock is hugely slower than `foreach ($el in $myArray) { }`

Comment: @wOxxOm: True.  Did not optimize for perf, but rather focused on the O(n).

Comment: @KoryGill I could have it sorted, but like I said it will run through many times and there's no way to keep the sort without re-sorting it every pass. Would you suggest sorting it every time or just using my own method of iterating through the array and retrieving the index of the minimum value?

Comment: Can't really answer that without knowing your entire workflow, which is beyond this question.  A sorted list may be overkill for your needs, and would change the concept of needing an index. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

its a problem of type, try like this:

```
$myArray = [int[]]5,66,4,33,2,9,9,12
$minvalue=[int]($myArray | measure -Minimum).Minimum
$myArray.IndexOf($minvalue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are 6 different options for you...

```
cls
$myArray = @(5,66,4,33,2,9,9,12)
$iterations = 50000

$t = (measure-command{
    foreach ($i in 1..$iterations) {
        $minValue = [int]($myArray | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
        $minIndex = $myArray.IndexOf($minValue)
    }
}).TotalSeconds
"measure-object with indexOf: $t"

$t = (measure-command{
    foreach ($i in 1..$iterations) {
        $index = 0
        $minIndex = 0
        $minValue = [int]::MaxValue
        $myArray | % { if ($minValue -gt $_) {$minValue = $_; $minIndex = $index}; $index++ }
    }
}).TotalSeconds
"pipeline with compare: $t"

$t = (measure-command{
    foreach ($i in 1..$iterations) {
        $minIndex = 0
        $minValue = [int]::MaxValue
        foreach ($index in 0..($myArray.count-1)) {
            if ($myArray[$index] -lt $minValue) {
                $minValue = $myArray[$index]
                $minIndex = $index
            } 
        }
    }
}).TotalSeconds
"foreach-loop with compare: $t"

$t = (measure-command{
    foreach ($i in 1..$iterations) {
        $h = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
        foreach ($index in 0..($myArray.count-1)) {
            $null = $h.add([tuple]::Create($myArray[$index], $index))
        }
        $h.Sort()
        $minIndex = $h[0].Item2
    }
}).TotalSeconds
"quicksort of a list of tuples: $t"

Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Linq;
public static class My {
    public static int indexOfMin(int[] arr){
        int min = arr.Min();
        return Array.IndexOf(arr, min);
    }
}
"@

$t = (measure-command{
    foreach ($i in 1..$iterations) {
        $minIndex = [my]::indexOfMin($myArray)
    }
}).TotalSeconds
"custom type and IndexOf: $t"

Add-Type @"
public static int[] indexOfMin(int[] arr){
        int min = int.MaxValue;
        int minIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
            if (arr[i]<min) {
                min = arr[i];
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return new int[] {min, minIndex};
    }
"@ -name My2 -Namespace System

$t = (measure-command{
    foreach ($i in 1..$iterations) {
        $minValue, $minIndex = [my2]::indexOfMin($myArray)
    }
}).TotalSeconds
"custom type and looping: $t"
```

Comment: Try to guess, which one is the slowest and which one is the fastest BEFORE running the samples ;-)