# What measure means in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Saw it here [Get minimum value in an array and then get index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033959/get-minimum-value-in-an-array-and-then-get-index)

```
$myArray = [int[]]5,66,4,33,2,9,9,12
$minvalue=[int]($myArray | measure -Minimum).Minimum
$myArray.IndexOf($minvalue)
```

but cannot find it means on Google as I can only find Measure-Object.

Comment: Quick tip: `Get-Command Measure`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to find out, what a command does (or more strictly, what it *is*), is to use `Get-Command`. For your case, it tells you that `Measure` is - like told already by the other answerees - an alias to [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-5.1):

```
PS> Get-Command measure

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           measure -> Measure-Object
```

What it really *does* can be found with `Get-Help` what - in your case - will result in:

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>     Calculates the numeric properties of objects, and the characters, words, and lines in string objects, such as files of text.
> ```

---

Note: `Get-Command` aliases to `gcm` and `Get-Help` to `help`. Keep in mind that while aliases may help you in interactive shells, they should be avoided in scripts.

Answer (score 5):

`Measure` is the standard PowerShell Alias for [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-5.1). Using `Measure` or `Measure-Object` does the exact same thing.

You can also verify this with PowerShell by running the command:

```
Get-Alias measure
```

Comment: I would add this as proof in the pudding `get-alias measure`

Comment: Although PowerShell isn't case sensitive, I prefer to comply with the casing. Last but not least it helps StackOverflow to syntax-highlight it.

Answer (score 1):

> Another common task in PowerShell is measuring a group of objects
>   based on some numeric property. The cmdlet to use for this task is
>   Measure-Object, which has an alias of measure. All you need to do is
>   specify the property name and the type of measurement to perform. The
>   cmdlet has parameters for adding values (-Sum), calculating the
>   average value (-Average), and finding the minimum value (-Minimum) and
>   maximum value (-Maximum).

Written by Jeffery Hicks From article: http://m.windowsitpro.com/powershell/powershell-basics-sorting-measuring-objects